# How to find the index of A in a list of B

Tags: python

Say we have a list `A = [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]` and `B = [[1,0],[0,0],[7,8],[1,1],[1,2]]`
and I would like to find the index for every elements from `A` in `B`, so I want to get the output `[0,3,4]`.

Comment: `[B.index(el) for el in A]` will find the *first* instance of each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop to iterate over A and then use B.index(). The code would be something like this

```py
result = []
for elem in A:
    index = B.index(elem) # Find the location of element
    result.append(index)  # Save it inside results
    # You can combine the above two statements into one
    # and remove the extra variable index if you like
```

Note that if there are duplicates in B, it will only find the first one

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I actually tried this method, but I got the error : ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Does the list B has duplicate values ?